# Quickly set property when objects are intersected?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, observablecollection

I have a performance problem when trying to set a property when an object is present in both list

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DerivateProduct : Product
{
    public bool isIntersected{ get; set; }
}


public class Storage
{
    public Product stProduct { get; set; }
}


//Approx 10,000 objects
ObservableCollection<DerivateProduct> Products;
//Approx 500 Objects
ObservableCollection<Storage> Storages;
```

I use the following code, it works, but the performance is pretty poor (about 4 seconds for a result)

```
Products.Where(cp => Storages.Any(b => b.stProduct.Id == cp.Id))
            .ToList()
            .All(cp => cp.isIntersected = true);
```

I tried the following and I get the correct number of iteration in only 150 milliseconds, but I don't see how I can set my `isIntersected=true` while having the same performance.

```
var intersectedId = Products.Select(cp => cp.Id)
            .Intersect(Storages.Select(b => b.stProduct.Id))
            .ToList();
```

I'm really in need of help. All answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Your English is not nearly as bad as most posters, don't worry ;)

Comment: @MongZhu No it's a mistake i made when simplifying my code, i remove it. It is not hided

Comment: @LonelyNeuron Thanks :)

Comment: the collection is created using Nhibernate and asking the DB it roughly take 4seconds but it take another 4seconds when performing the 
    Where()..All() query

Comment: @MongZhu Thanks fot the guess i have investigated a bit further. It's seems like no Db or Orm call are made when executing the code (had cleand the debug output, nothing came. 
Based on your guess i have dropped the ToList it is not necessary but the the execution time is still about 4seconds :(

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Populate `Storages.Select(b => b.stProduct.Id)` into a `HashSet`. Then iterate over the `Products` using a `foreach` or `for` or whatever. For each `Product` do `HashSet.Exists` check (which may be faster than your `Any` check, depending on how large each of your `ObservableCollection`s are). If it is there, set `isIntersected` to `true`.

Comment: @mjwills Perfect :) works just fine with a 5ms

    var stPrIds = Storages.Select(b => b.stProduct.Id).ToArray();

        foreach (var item in products.Where(cp => stPrIds .Contains(cp.Id)).ToList())
        {
            item.IsBiocontrol = true;
        }

Comment: Great news @Dice249.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

THANKS a lot to @mjwills it works just fine with a 5ms

```
var stPrIds = Storages.Select(b => b.stProduct.Id).ToArray(); 
foreach (var item in products.Where(cp => stPrIds .Contains(cp.Id)).ToList()) 
{ 
item.IsBiocontrol = true; 
}
```

Comment: That is not what I suggested. I suggested using a `HashSet`.